# How to use || in Keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-calculator

I want to map a keyboard key to this command:

```
wmctrl -a Calculator || gnome-calculator
```

This works fine when I run it in the terminal, but it doesn't seem to work when I set up a shortcut for this. I'm guessing it doesn't like the `||`.

Specifically, it will focus the calculator if it's already open, but it won't open it if it's not already open (which is what the OR condition is supposed to do).

How can I work around this?

[image]

Comment: `|` is a pipe in bash.  I don't think the command is actually 'working fine', it just appears to be in this circumstance.

Comment: @earthmeLon `|` is pipe, but isn't `||` or? Regardless, I'm thinking maybe this Keyboard shortcut thinger isn't running bash? But that gives me an idea...I could do `sh -c` couldn't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the keyboard shorcuts are ran through bash, so `||` won't work. However, you can do this:

```
sh -c 'wmctrl -Fxa gnome-calculator.Gnome-calculator || gnome-calculator'
```

`-F` means match the full title case-sensitively, and `-a` means activate/focus said program, `-x` means select by the "WM_CLASS" name which you can get by running `wmctrl -xl`.

Comment: Correct, pipes are not accepted within shortcut definitions, but can be used via calling shell and executing commands within that shell

Comment: doesn't seem to be working on ubuntu 20.10